# Intel C++ error: "pair" is not a nonstatic data member or base class of class "std::pair<const int, double>"

Tags: c++, qt-creator, qmake, icc

I'm using Intel C++ compiler together with qmake in QtCreator. In my project I use a std::map.

```
std::map<int,double> dataBase;
dataBase[2] = 2.445;
```

This code compiles and runs without any problems using g++. If I try to compile with ICC the following error occurs:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8.0/tuple(1075): error: "pair" is not a nonstatic data member or base class of class "std::pair<const int, double>"
```

Full compiler error is much longer. I'm a little confused about the include path because for me it looks like a g++ library which is used. If I comment out this section program compiles and I can verify that the ICC was used.

Does anybody know why the Intel C++ compiler causes this error?

Edit:

I create a minimal example and found the compiler option causing this problem:
Folowing is content of the *.pro file

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    map<int,double> dataBase;
    dataBase[2] = 2.445;
    cout << dataBase[2] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It works without the

```
-std=c++11
```

but causes compiler error with it.

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same problem as you are describing..., really strange. Every other compiler (clang, gcc, msvc11) compiles it without any problem. I guess it's because of the 4.8.x headers. `icpc -v` says at least `version 13.1.1 (gcc version **4.7.0** compatibility)`...

Workaround:

```
template<class K, class V>
V &changemapvalue(std::map<K, V> &map, K &key, V &val)
{
#if defined(__GNUC__) && defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)
    if (map.find(key) != map.end()) map.erase(key);
    map.insert(std::pair<K, V>(key, val));
#else
    map[key] = val;
#endif //__GNUC__ && __INTEL_COMPILER
    return val;
}
```

But it's stupid.

Comment: I have the similar problem. Anyway you can use `#ifdef __ICC` instead of the long test.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider a `vector<char>`, a single element is represented as simply a `char`.

A `map` however (and the other associative containers) are not represented this way. Rather, they are represented as a `pair`:

### {C++03} 23.3.1/2

```
typedef pair<const Key, T> value_type;
```

I'm not familiar with the Intel C++ compiler, but judging from the error message I'd say that Intel implements `pair` in terms of a `tuple` class.  A tuple class is an N-ary aggregate of things.  A `pair` for example would be a `tuple` with two elements.

All of the above is simply elaboration, and doesn't really speak to why you're getting this error.  `/usr/include/c++/4.8.0` looks to me like the include directory for G++ 4.8.0 -- the latest version of G++.  If the Intel compiler is looking here, I'd say your paths are messed up, either in your environment or in the paths sent to the Intel compiler.

Check your environment variables and your makefile.

Comment: I checked this out and used a plain test.cpp with the code above. It compiles without the c++11 flag on intel but not with it. I clean the path and icpc is search for the libstdc++ and libgcc while compiling. Why is the intel compiler using the gcc libraries? Does Intel C++ comes with own stdc++ library?

Comment: This is nto "path mess up" issue. Because Intel C Compiler uses libstdc++ and various C++ header files from GNU C++ compiler. Also, in earlier Clang it also uses various GNU C++ files.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to c++11 for some reasons icpc doesn't like the operator[] of std::map.

For inserting new values you need to use the method `insert()` while to access existing values you can use the c++11 method `at()`.

This compiles correctely with `icpc -std=c++11`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    map<int,double> dataBase;
    dataBase.insert(pair<int,double>(2,2.445));
    cout << dataBase.at(2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```